# Autocomplete multiple textfields using jquery, php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have the following php code to auto complete a single text field, that works; However what Im trying to make it do is auto complete fields: app_trn(that works), app_fname, app_lname with the same criteria i have

```
<?php

if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )
    exit;

$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('lms');

$rs = mysql_query('select app_trn, app_fname, app_lname from applicant where app_trn like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" 
order by app_trn asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['app_trn'] .', '. $row['app_fname'] .' '. $row['app_lname'] ,
            'value' => $row['app_trn']
        );
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

And this is the jquery script linking the auto complete to textfield: 'app_trn' in the html form:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#app_trn').autocomplete({source:'suggest_zip.php', minLength:2});
});
```

Comment: Split the label on the comma and then assign the data to the appropriate field.

Comment: like this?
'label' => $row['app_trn'] .' '. $row['app_fname'] .' '. $row['app_lname'] ,
            'value' => $row['app_trn'] .' '. $row['app_fname'] .' '. $row['app_lname']

Comment: No, in jQuery split the returned json label on the commas. Can you post an example of the json your script returns? Judging from your example, the label contains three comma delimited values.

Comment: Im a little new to jquery,but is this it?
{c=this.options.source;this.source=function(d,b){e.getJSON(c,d,b)}}else this.source=this.options.source}

Comment: I Really wish if someone could help me

Comment: Can you post a sample of the returned JSON?

Comment: nt sure exactly where is the returned JSON located, im new to jquery..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9798/discussion-between-dames-and-j08691)